# Getting a CGFloat instance variable from another class implementation

Tags: objective-c, ios, class, variables, implementation

I'm quite new to Objective C development and I was wondering how I could get a CGFloat value out of an instance variable of a class in another class.

Let's say I've got a class A in which the CGFloat is an instance variable.

How can  I in the implementation of class B get that CGFloat in class A ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a getter in class A:

```
- (CGFloat)myFloat
{
    return myFloat;
}
```

Or use a property (essentially the same thing, just less typing in most cases):

In ClassA.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat myFloat;
```

in ClassA.m:

```
@synthesize myFloat;
```

Comment: What about class B ? 
I did #import "ClassA.h" in ClassB.m and tried getting to the instance variable using 
this method  ClassA.myFloat
But that doesn't work

Comment: I can't get it into another variable.

Comment: `ClassA.myFloat` won't work, it has to be an _initialized instance_ of the class, not the class itself.

Comment: Can I declare myFloat and it's instance in the same class ?